# Navigation Conctroller, не отображается navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, navigationcontroller

В интерфейсе присутствует navigation bar, и в нем расположена кнопка "Выйти"
Однако при запуске, этого меню просто нет(скриншоты ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте вместо обычной UIButton использовать UIBarButtonItem

Comment: @ВикторМишустин добавил, ничего не изменилось, этого меню сверху нет, а соответственно и всех его компонентов

Comment: может бар скрыт, попробуйте в классе контроллера прописать self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

Comment: @ВикторМишустин он не скрыт, проверил p.s. нижняя часть тоже не отображается, проблема именно с самим навигатором, словно он не подключен

Comment: Скорее всего она перекрыта, эту кнопку нужно в сториборде перетащить вверх по иерархии.

Comment: @OrestMykha добавил скриншот иерархии

Comment: Все нормально, а если кодом добавить: UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
backButton.title = @"Вийти";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте, стоит ли у вас галочка на Show Navigation Bar
[image: Navigation bar]